# Centering disregarding symbol ®

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have a titlepage for a report. This title is split into two lines with only the word "BRAND®" on the second. It should be centered, but should disregard the ® as it is placed in the third line (which is for demonstration only).

```
\begin{center}  
    Report with longer title that should break right before the word\\
    BRAND\textsuperscript{\textregistered}\\
    BRAND
\end{center}
```

[image]

How can I do this?

(pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9), on Windows 7 x64, if this does matter)

Comment: Great! This works.

Comment: BRAND\\\textsuperscript{\textregistered}\\

Answer (score 11):

Put the ® in an `\rlap`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    Report with longer title that should break right before the word\\
    BRAND\rlap{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}\\
    BRAND
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I would like better seeing `\makebox[0pt][l]{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}`; it's a bit longer but much safer. Not everybody knows that `\rlap` (and also `\llap`, of course) doesn't start a paragraph and this might have surprising effects.

Answer (score 10):

The obvious remedy is to set the “registered” mark so that it occupies no horizontal space; of course it must appear at the end of the line.

The documented way in LaTeX is `\makebox`:

```
\begin{center}
Report with longer title that should break right before the word\\
BRAND\makebox[0pt][l]{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}\\
BRAND
\end{center}
```

With `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` you are ordering to typeset the text inside a rectangle of zero width, with the contents next to the left margin of this box. The result is that it sticks on the right of this zero width box (and occupies no space as far as TeX is concerned).

If you need such a zero width symbol several times, it's better to define a couple  of shortcuts:

```
\newcommand{\reg}{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}
\newcommand{\zreg}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\reg}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed my first option will be also a `\makebox` (I overuse this command) or `\rlap` (also overused, good to know that doesn't start a paragraph) or just being imaginative, another sizable box, from `\hbox` to a `\parbox` or even a `minipage`,  but just for fun,  a complete different approach: adding a equivalent phantom space on the left:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\def\R{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}

\newlength\spaR
\setlength{\spaR}{\widthof{\R}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

    Report with longer title that should break right before the word

    \hspace{\spaR}BRAND\R

    BRAND

    BRAND\hbox to 0pt \R


    BRAND\parbox{0pt}\R

    BRAND

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice idea! But why haven't you use `\phantom` or `\hphantom`?

Comment: @quinmars Have you tried `\hphantom{\R}BRAND\R` in this example? Don't work. It must have something to the left as a `\mbox{}` to obtain the same result. But why make this even more complicated? `:)`